# Why doesn't the animate function of jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code doesn't work. I followed exactly the syntax for animate() but not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #testing {
      background-color: skyblue;
      Position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#testing").animate({
          width: 100%,
          height: 100%
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Hide</button>
  <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
  <div id="testing">Testing</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It throws no error at all and doesn't perform the intended functionality.

Comment: where do you what it to animate? you already have `height: 100%; width:100%;` in your CSS

Comment: You need to use `"100%"`; but even if `100%` were a valid number, you're animating from 100% to 100%...

Comment: `It throws no error at all` That's clearly not the case from the snippet I added to your question.

Comment: Either that's not the real code or you didn't look for errors at the right place, because that would throw a syntax error.

Comment: @ChrisG: tried 10% but still not working

Comment: @shershen: tried 10% but not working

Comment: Put the value in quotes: `width: '10%',`

Comment: try put it to jsfiddle.net and post a link here

Comment: Did you try `width: "10%", height: "10%"` ...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: It is as it seems

Comment: Like shershen says, the starting dimensions of the `div` is already that to which you are 'changing' it to. I would change the size of the `div` to pixels and then animate it to double that size. When something like this doesn't seem to work I always start small by changing 1 property instead of multiple and add more when that works.
Alo, looking at the examples on the `jquery` website the parameters in the animate function have `'` surrounding the values: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @ChrisG yes, it works but it only reflects the width property in animation, not height i.e. it expands in width but not in height

Comment: I don't know what values you are currently using in your CSS / `animate()`, however this question is now dealt with, so you can go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @Covert to set the height of an element, all parent elements (including the `body` and even `html`) must have a `height` attribute set, and to a value other than `auto` or `inherit`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hafx8uaf/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#testing").animate({
      width: "0%",
      height: "0%"
    });
  });
});
```

Here you have a working JsFiddle.
You need to set the width and height to "0%" in your JS if you want to hide the div when the button is clicked. if you animate to 100% there will be no effect as it is already at 100% in the CSS.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your CSS style, `#testing` already has a width of 100% and a height of 100%, so the code might well be working, it's just already at the end point of the animation.

Try updating your CSS to

```
<style>
    #testing
    {
        background-color: skyblue;
        Position: absolute;
        height: 10%;
        width: 10%;
    }
</style>
```

And it will probably work.

EDIT: You would also need to add double quotes around your width/height conditions on .animate, so

```
width: "100%", 
height: "100%"
```

Otherwise it will return a syntax error.

Comment: There is also a syntax problem with the JS. This doesn't solve the issue - which is why you're drowning in downvotes.

Comment: Yeah just noticed that. Updated the answer to reflect that, although this is quite a silly question to begin with.